# non-split extension and Schur multiplier

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$  be a central extension of the group $K$  by the simple non-abelian group $H$ ($K$ is the normal subgroup). If we know that this extension is non-split, is it true that the order of $K$  must divide the Schur multiplier of the group $H$ ? (Note that all groups are finite)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, $K$ can be as large as you like. Let $G$ be the direct product of ${\rm SL}_2(5)$ (the covering group of $H=A_5$) and any abelian group $L$, and let $K = Z \times L$, where $Z = Z({\rm SL}_2(5))$.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks alot. What about the case in which  $(|K|,|M(H)|)=1$? I mean whether in this case we can conclude that the extension has to  split?

Comment: Yes, if $H$ is simple (in fact $H$ perfect is enough) and $(|K|,|M(H)|)=1$ then the extension has to split. The commutator subgroup is a complement.

Comment: Thanks a million for your help.