# Central extension and direct product

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-extensions

Let $G,H,K$ be finite groups and suppose $G$ is a
 [central extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension#Central_extension)
   of $H$ by $K$. The question is that under which condition on this extension we will have $G \cong  K \times  H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will have $G \cong  K \times  H$, if and only if the extension 
$$
1\rightarrow K\rightarrow G\rightarrow H\rightarrow 1
$$
[splits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension), which means that its equivalence class is the trivial one in the second cohomology group $H^2(H,K)$.

Comment: I would say rather that if $H^2(G,A)=0$ (what is $A$?) then the extension defnitely splits, but otherwise it may or may not split.

Comment: $A$ stands for abelian, because it is a $G$-module. I have adapted the notation.

Comment: Can we get to this extension by putting some conditions on the groups $H,K$? I found a [relative question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501150/non-split-extension-and-schur-multiplier) where  @DerekHolt   has answered and left a comment on splitting extensions giving conditions on $H,K$. My other question is that is there any reference dealing with this subjects?

Comment: We get this extensions without any further conditions, by using the obvious injection $K\rightarrow K\times H$, and the obvious surjection $K\times H\rightarrow H$. There are really many references, e.g.  all texts on group cohomology. I have a [lecture note](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_16_coho_course.pdf), too.

Comment: @DietrichBurde

If   $H$ is  perfect and $(|K|,|{\rm Mult}(H)|)=1$ then can we claim that the central extension results the direct product $ G \cong H \times K $. In general, we look for such conditions on $H,K$.

Comment: Yes, this is true. Another condition is $H^2(H,K)=0$, as I said.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Is there any other conditions?

Comment: Well, see Theorem $3.3$ [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwi0psLAn-_SAhVKKMAKHRvADKYQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fgrouptheory%2Fsplittinggp.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFCKdspc_BHDm938WHUXOdtRNGoIA&sig2=6zldjonU70kBKO_4zNpbCw&bvm=bv.150475504,d.ZGg). It splits if and only we have a semidirect product. There are many equivalent formulations for this, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898697/equivalent-conditions-for-an-exact-sequence-of-groups-being-split).

Comment: Is a direct product $K \times H$ of *any* two groups $H$ and $K$ (even non-abelian ones) necessarily a central extension of $K$ by $H$ or $H$ by $K$? I'm a bit confused as I hear people say that direct products are central split extensions. But non-abelian subgroups can't be in the center of any group!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what sort of answer you are looking for, but it is true that it is a direct sum if and only if the sequence *left splits*, i.e. if for the short exact sequence $1 \rightarrow K \xrightarrow{\psi} G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1$ there is a group homomorphism $\phi: G \rightarrow K$ "back" in such a way that $\phi \circ \psi = id_K $. This is part of the [Splitting Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma#Non-abelian_groups).